# Displaying a MySql TIMEDIFF() in a DB grid

Tags: mysql, delphi, anydac

When I use the command line, this query gives me pleasing results (it shows duation, which is what TIMEDIFF is about):

```
mysql> select timediff(end_time_stamp,start_time_stamp) from test_runs;
+-------------------------------------------+
| timediff(end_time_stamp,start_time_stamp) |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 00:00:07                                  |
| 00:00:11                                  |
| 00:01:23                                  |
+-------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I put it in a DB grid in Delphi, the TIMEDIFFs are formatted like `12:00:07 AM`, which is not what I want (that looks like a time, not a duration).

I am using AnyDac and when I open the query editor at design time and execute it, the result is also `12:00:07 AM`, so it seems that AnyDac is formatting it for some reason.

How can I get output like 00:00:07 (a duration, not a time)?

- Can I tweak the AnyDac query?
- Can I explicitly format the output using the MySql statement?
- Is thare an OnXXX() function which I can code to reformt (and how)?

---

[Update] Well, this ugly piece of code does what I want, but is there a more elegant way?

```
SELECT run_id,
       start_time_stamp,
       end_time_stamp,
       CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(LPAD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timediff(end_time_stamp,start_time_stamp)), 2, '0'), ":"),LPAD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM timediff(end_time_stamp,start_time_stamp)), 2, '0'), ":"), LPAD(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM timediff(end_time_stamp,start_time_stamp)), 2, '0'))) AS duration,
       description

FROM test_runs ORDER BY start_time_stamp DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DisplayFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat) property of the `TField` object to get the result you want, for example:

```
begin
  MyQuery.Open;
  MyQueryField.DisplayFormat := 'hh:nn:ss';
  //or casting a TField to a descendant, like this:
  (MyQuery.FieldByName('duration') as TDateTimeField).DisplayFormat := 'hh:nn:ss';
end;
```

#### Edit

I added a cast to TDateTimeField. If your actual field is not an instance of TDateTimeField or a descendant it will result in a EInvalidTypeCast exception, since you have to cast it to the correct class it belongs to.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I am too dumb to understand your answer. This is the closest I could get `      TestRunsOverviewADQuery.FieldByName('duration').DisplayFormat := 'hh:nn:ss';` and it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Mawg doesn't compile is not a good description of what the compiler tells you. What's the error message?

Comment: [DCC Error] fMainForm.pas(711): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'DisplayFormat'

Comment: @Mawg: that is because FieldByName returns a TField, and DisplayFormat introduced in one of its descendants. You'll have to cast it to the actual type of the field instance.

Comment: @MarjanVenema +1 Can you tell me how?

Comment: @Mawg: hmm, a proper answer would require a look at more code than your question is showing. As you don't seem to be using persistent fields: check out the db unit. Find TField, find its descendants, figure out where DisplayFormat is introduced. Use a soft `as` cast `(FieldByName() as TSomeTypeOfField).DisplayFormat` and quard against an EInvalidCast exception.